# gRPC says one function "not implemented", rest are fine

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

All functions were made at the exact same time and work as intended. I can call them locally and they all work. BUT gRPC won't call `List()`.

`rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = method List not implemented`

I've tried deleting the pb.go file, renaming functions, etc. Double checked my return types, tried to return pointers/non-pointers. It is ONLY `List()` that doesn't work. It returns an empty `ResponseCollection`.

Here's my `.proto`:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package service;

message Response {
    bool IsMe = 1;
    bool Response = 2;
    string Message = 3; 
}

message Instance {
    string Name = 1;
    bool Live = 2;
    int32 Port = 4;
}

message ResponseCollection {
    repeated Instance Message = 1; 
}

message Name {
    string Name = 1;
}

message Register {
    string Name = 1;
    string IP = 2;
    int32 Port = 3;
    bool Register = 41;
}

message Comm {
    string Name = 1;
    repeated string Command = 2;
}

message Void {}

service ServerService {
    rpc Start(Name) returns (Response) {}
    rpc Stop(Name) returns (Response) {}
    rpc Restart(Name) returns (Response) {}
    rpc Update(Name) returns (Response) {}
    rpc List(Void) returns (ResponseCollection) {}
    rpc RegisterServer(Register) returns (ResponseCollection) {}
    rpc Reregister(Void) returns (Response) {}
    rpc Command(Comm) returns (Response) {}
    rpc Check(Name) returns (Response) {}
}
```

Running client side:

```golang
r, _ := c.Stop(ctx, &service.Name{Name: args.Name})
r, _ := c.Restart(ctx, &service.Name{Name: args.Name})
r, _ := c.Update(ctx, &service.Name{Name: args.Name})
r, _ := c.List(ctx, &service.Void{})
r, _ := c.RegisterServer(ctx, &service.Register{Name: args.Name, IP: addr.String(), Port: int32(conf.port), Register: args.Register})
r, _ := c.Reregister(ctx, &service.Void{})
r, _ := c.Command(context.Background(), &service.Comm{Name: args.Name, Command: args.Command})
r, _ := c.Check(context.Background(), &service.Name{Name: args.Name})
```

The prototypes server-side:

```golang
func (h *ServerHandler) Start(ctx context.Context, name string) *Response
func (h *ServerHandler) Stop(ctx context.Context, name string) *Response
func (h *ServerHandler) Restart(ctx context.Context, name string) *Response
func (h *ServerHandler) Update(ctx context.Context, name string) *Response
func (h *ServerHandler) List(ctx context.Context) *ResponseCollection
func (h *ServerHandler) RegisterServer(ctx context.Context, name string, ip string, port int, register bool) *ResponseCollection
func (h *ServerHandler) Reregister(ctx context.Context) *Response
func (h *ServerHandler) Command(ctx context.Context, name string, command ...string) *Response
func (h *ServerHandler) Check(ctx context.Context, name string) *Response
```

And the structs:

```golang
type ResponseCollection struct {
    Message []Instance `json:"message"`
}

type Response struct {
    IsMe     bool   `json:"isMe"`
    Response bool   `json:"response"`
    Message  string `json:"message"`
}
```

I've been banging my head on the table for a few hours now. Anyone see something I don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the *Void argument:

```
- func (h *ServerHandler) List(ctx context.Context) *ResponseCollection
+ func (h *ServerHandler) List(ctx context.Context, _ *Void) *ResponseCollection
```

To debug these kinds of problems, embed the Unsafe* interface in your server instead of the forward compatible one that returns Unimplemented for all methods:

```
type ServerHandler struct {
    UnsafeServerServiceServer
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot. I noticed that "Reregister" also was missing the `Void` in there. However, it looks like Reregister works both with and without the `Void`, but "List" still does not work. Also I'm not sure what you mean with the `Unsafe` interface. The only thing that `service` has is `UnimplementedServerServiceServer` right now.

Comment: UnimplementedServerServiceServer is what responds with Unimplemented. Replace it with UnsafeServerServiceServer to get compile time checks instead.

Comment: Turns out I had some other bad code, you were right. I'm still not sure I understand this UnsafeServer part. When I put in `UnsafeServerServiceServer` is just says `undeclared name`.

Comment: If you don't have the Unsafe* type then you're using a fairly old version of go-grpc. It has been added in [this PR](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/pull/3911) after a [long debate here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/3669). Removing the embedded type entirely should also work (may require compiling with `--go-grpc_out=require_unimplemented_servers=false[,other options...]:.`, depending on the version).